# Use Custom Font in DrawText Wpf C#

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, fonts

I have a custom OTF font in the *Resources* folder in my project which is not installed on my *Windows*.
The *Build Action* of the font is already set to *Resource*.

Now I want to use `DrawText` method and `FormattedText` class to write some text on visual layer.

How can I use this custom font for the `FormattedText`. I already know how to do this say for a TextBlock in XAML using the below code. But what about code-behind?

```
<TextBlock FontFamily="pack://application:,,,/Resources/#Quicksand Light"> 
    StackOverflow
</TextBlock>
```

Here is the code I'm using to define my FormattedText object.

```
var f = new FontFamily("pack://application:,,,/Resources/#Quicksand Light");
var typeface = new Typeface(f, new FontStyle(), new FontWeight(), new FontStretch());
var cultureinfo = new CultureInfo("en-us");
var ft = new FormattedText("Stackoverflow", cultureinfo, FlowDirection.LeftToRight,
    typeface, 28, Brushes.White)
dc.DrawText(ft, new Point(0,0));
```

My problem is is defining the font for typeface so that I can use it in fotmattedtext.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var typeface = new Typeface(new FontFamily(new Uri("pack://application:,,,/"), "/Resources/#Quicksand Light"), FontStyles.Normal, FontWeights.Regular, FontStretches.Normal);
```